# Access $_GET argument from inside .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, response-headers

I have on my server images with random names (f.e. "8a4f5d61.jpg") and I need to change name of those files using given GET argument.

So if I have such URL:

> http://my.server/8a4f5d61.jpg?attachement=custom_name.jpg

and I want Apache to add header like this:

> Header Content-Disposition: "attachement, filename=$_GET['attachement']"

so user will download this file already renamed into "custom_name.jpg".

I have no clue how to get that GET argument from inside .htaccess

---

On nginx it's very easy, here's my working nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/.*\.jpg$ {
    if ($arg_inline) {
        add_header Content-Disposition "inline; filename=$arg_inline";
    }
    if ($arg_attachement) {
        add_header Content-Disposition "attachement; filename=$arg_attachement";
    }
}
```

Is it achievable on Apache with .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but theoretically, set an environment variable if your query matches the given criteria and later, use [`mod_headers`' Header](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_headers#header) directive to set the header:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^attachment=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=file_name:%1,L]

Header always set Content-Disposition "attachement; filename=%{file_name}e" env=file_name
```

where the `%{file_name}e` is the environment value for `file_name`.

Comment: It needs to be `[E=file_name:%1,L]` (plz fix your post) and it's working very nicely :) Thank you!

Comment: @a6r Fixed, thanks! I expected at least one mistake in the code :P Glad to know that it is working though. :)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also needed to remove `env=file_name`, perhaps server related thing...